# How can I make my loop start over after a timer?

Tags: python

How can I make this code to start the while loop again until the user will put the right password?

```
userPassword =input('parola;')
userPasswordId = input('parola')
counter = 0
while userPasswordId != userPassword and counter < 3:
    print('Sorry the password is incorect.Try again!')
    counter = counter + 1
    print('You have', 3 - counter, 'attempts left.')
 userPasswordId = input('Enter your password:')
if counter == 3:
    print('Your account is locked for 30 seconds!!!!!')
    import time
    sec = 0
    while sec != 5:
        print('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>', sec)
    # Sleep for a sec
        time.sleep(1)
    # Increment the minute total
        sec += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to move that `if counter == 3` line and the block below it into the `while` loop.

To improve the flow of messages that the user sees, I've refactored the code a bit as well.

Here's an example:

```
import time


userPassword =input('parola;')
counter = 0

while True:
    userPasswordId = input('Enter your password:')
    if userPasswordId != userPassword:
        print('Sorry the password is incorect.Try again!')
        counter += 1
        print('You have', 3 - counter, 'attempts left.')
    else:
        break

    if counter == 3:
        counter = 0
        print('Your account is locked for 30 seconds!!!!!')
        sec = 0
        while sec != 5:
            print('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>', sec)
        # Sleep for a sec
            time.sleep(1)
        # Increment the minute total
            sec += 1
```

This code will continue to loop until the user enters the correct password, at which point it will `break` execution of the loop.

Comment: yes but after 30 sec first message is 'Sorry the password is incorect.Try again!' Your account is locked for 30 seconds!!!!!
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 0
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 1
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 2
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 3
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 4
Sorry the password is incorect.Try again!
You have 2 attempts left.
Enter your password:

Comment: @AndreiSebi I've edited my answer to improve this, have a look!

Answer (score 0):

It's called asynchronous programing. It has been introduce in Python with async and await keyword.

```
import asyncio 
async def allowInput():
    await asyncio.sleep(30000) #ms
    # your code goes here
```